# Show Slave Status not working from console, nor client

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I have a somewhat strange case.

Whenever one of my coworkers executes this line:

**show slave status;**

from their MySQL clients, it works smoothly. But if I do that, it says:

**ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the SUPER,REPLICATION CLIENT privilege for this operation**

We are all going against the same database, and if I check privileges I can see:

**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'usermysql'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'**

There's something wrong with my computer.. but I can't pinpoint where it is..

Thanks

---

EDIT:

It's kinda bizarre.. it goes through a VPN remotely. But if I change the internet connection, then it works.. If the previous internet connection is restored, it doesn't..

Could we classify this among the great mysteries of the world? Or someone has an idea?

Answer (score 4):

```
GRANT RELOAD, PROCESS, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'
```

**REPLICATION CLIENT**

Comment: This is what I have done, still getting that error.

Comment: For me this query cleared the issue, Thank @ T D S

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` should include REPLICATION CLIENT. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES is basically super access.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL distinquishes between localhost and 'other' systems.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'usermysql'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'
```

gives the 'others' access. To give the system where the database is running access you'll need to also grnat permission to localhost:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'usermysql'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not connecting locally, therefore, I'm not @'localhost'. I do exactly the same thing as my coworkers. Anyway, I gave it a try, didn't work..

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by granting the SUPER privilege to your user.

SUPER can only be assigned globally and global privileges are in mysql.user

To identify why this isn't working when it is for your coworkers, you will need to compare the grants for your user and their user.

```
mysql > use mysql;

mysql >select User,Host,Super_priv,Repl_client_priv from user;
```

See if there is a difference for you and your coworkers.

Comment: Thanks Richard, but we are all using the same user. Funny though, if I change the internet connection it works, but all of my coworkers are on the connection that doesn't function for me! It's indeed a mystery..